# How to send message from Deadletter topic to Main and complete it using .net core c#

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azureservicebus

I'm able to send message to Main from Deadletter using below code but issue is unable to complete that message.

error at this line - 
`await deadletterReceiver.CompleteAsync(newMessage.SystemProperties.LockToken);`

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object.    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message.SystemPropertiesCollection.ThrowIfNotReceived()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message.SystemPropertiesCollection.get_LockToken()

```cs
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    try
    {

        var deadQueuePath = EntityNameHelper.FormatDeadLetterPath("demo/subscriptions/demo");

        MessageReceiver deadletterReceiver = new MessageReceiver(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStringSettingName"), deadQueuePath, ReceiveMode.PeekLock,RetryPolicy.Default);
        MessageSender sender = new MessageSender(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStringSettingName"), "demo",RetryPolicy.Default);

        var deadLetter = await deadletterReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
        if (deadLetter != null)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"got new message");

            Message newMessage = new Message(deadLetter.Body)
            {
                ContentType = deadLetter.ContentType,
                CorrelationId = deadLetter.CorrelationId                          
            };

            //Send the message to the Active Queue
            await sender.SendAsync(newMessage);
            await deadletterReceiver.CompleteAsync(newMessage.SystemProperties.LockToken); //Unlock the message and remove it from the DLQ
            log.LogInformation($"Unlock the message and remove it from the DLQ");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Exception: {ex}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you tell us exactly what the error is? That's critical to the question and shouldn't be left out. And while you're at it take the time to format your code so it's more easily readable. Remove all that whitespace that isn't necessary.

Comment: oh sorry my bad.. updated with error description , hope that will be helpful thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using the lock token from the deadletter message?

Essentially change this line of code:

```
 await deadletterReceiver.CompleteAsync(newMessage.SystemProperties.LockToken); //Unlock the message and remove it from the DLQ
```

to

```
 await deadletterReceiver.CompleteAsync(deadLetter.SystemProperties.LockToken); //Unlock the message and remove it from the DLQ
```

Comment: thanks a lot ... how to read all possible messages at one go ?  have 5 messaged then at a time it will process only one :(

Comment: Please try to use `ReceiveBatchAsync()` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.receivebatchasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_MessageReceiver_ReceiveBatchAsync_System_Int32_

Comment: I tried ReceiveBatchAsync but i think using i'm using .netcore gives error like -
'MessageReceiver' does not contain a definition for 'ReceiveBatchAsync

Comment: i can do maxcount like this ReceiveAsync(10); will it affect ? how much maximum is good pls guide thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I am not too familiar with .Net Core. I'm hoping that someone who's an expert there will take a look and answer that. I would suggest posting a new question (to get more eyeballs).